# Why using erase and unique function to remove duplicate vectors from a 2d vector is adding an extra empty vector in 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I am using the below code to remove duplicate vectors from a 2d vector

```
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
final_vec.erase(unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end()));
```

Can someone explain me why this is happening and what change should I make.

Comment: Try separating out your argument expressions into separate variables.  That will expose where the problem is in this code snippet.

Comment: [vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) has a couple overloads. The one you call is overload 1: Erasing a single element. What you want is overload 2: Erasing all elements from `unique(...)` until `final_vec.end()`. That would be `final_vec.erase(unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end()), final_vec.end());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it clearer what exactly is going wrong, I'm going to introduce an intermediate variable to store the iterator returned by [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique).

Your code is equivalent to:

```cpp
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
auto new_ending_iterator = unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end())
final_vec.erase(new_ending_iterator);
```

When we check the overloads of [std::vector::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), we see that this is actually the one-argument `erase` call:

> ```
> iterator erase( const_iterator pos )
> ```
>
> 1. Removes the element at `pos`.

So this is erasing a single element from `final_vec`. However, our goal is to erase every element from `new_ending_iterator` all the way until `final_vec.end()`. To do so, we use the second overload of `erase`:

> ```
> iterator erase( const_iterator first, const_iterator last );
> ```
>
> 2. Removes the elements in the range `[first, last)`.

The correct code would therefore look like

```cpp
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
auto new_ending_iterator = unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end())
final_vec.erase(new_ending_iterator, final_vec.end());
```

Or, if you really want to keep it all in one line:

```cpp
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
final_vec.erase(unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end()), final_vec.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
final_vec.erase(unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end()));
```

I made changes in the second line and it worked for me.

Apparently, `vector:erase` has a several overloads: one to delete a single element and other to delete all elements in given rangr. I was using first one, which was wrong, but now, with a change, it's working for me.

Syntax for the correct overload of `vector:erase` and the solution for this error is below

```
sort(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end());
final_vec.erase(unique(final_vec.begin(), final_vec.end()), final_vec.end());
```